# If $a_0,....a_n$ are the set of residues modulo $n$ and $\gcd(a,n)=1$, prove that $aa_0,aa_1,....,aa_n$ is also a complete set of residue modulo $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:**  If $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,....a_n$ are the set of residues modulo $n$ and $\gcd(a,n)=1$, prove that $aa_0,aa_1,aa_2,aa_3,....,aa_n$ is also a complete set of residue modulo $n$.

I have trouble in identifying what exactly should I show in order to prove this statement. In my opinion, the condition for having a complete set of residues is:

1. $aa_i\neq aa_j$ for any $0\leq i,j\leq n.$
2. $aa_i$ is not congruent to $aa_j$ for any $0\leq i,j\leq n.$

It is trivial to prove $1$ and $2$, but I would like to know whether both the conditions are sufficient or not.

Comment: Your conditions 1. and 2. appear identical. Both establish that there is no repetition in the set, but neither establishes that the set is *complete*.

Comment: You still have to show that, for any $i$, there is some $j$ such that $aa_j\equiv a_i$.

Comment: condition 2 guarantees that there are $n$ different residue classes in ${a_1,...a_n}$. Since there are only $n$ residue classes mod $n$ this is sufficient to show that they are all present.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)?

Comment: @EricTowers I am.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs But the second condition proves that there are $n$ different remainders, which must take the values from $0$ to $n-1$. Why? because there are exactly $n$ different residue classes and so the set $\{aa_0....aa_n\}$ must contain exactly one element from each residue class making it a complete residue system modulo.

Comment: Did you intend $\neq$ or $\not\equiv$ in $(1)?\ \ $

Comment: I didn't know how to write the second symbol in latex. But I've learnt it now. Will make the edit soon. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{\overline{a_1},...,\overline{a_n}\}$ be the set of residue classes mod $n$, and let $B=\{\overline{aa_1},...\overline{aa_n}\}$. Clearly $|A|=n$ and $B\subseteq A$. Since $\gcd(a,n)=1$, $\overline a$ has a multiplicative inverse mod $n$. The function

$$f(\overline x)=\overline{a^{-1}}\overline x$$

is then a bijection from $B$ to $A$. Therefore $|B|=|A|=n$, and hence $B=A$.

Alternatively, this will also work if you can prove $aa_i \not\equiv aa_j\pmod n$ for $1\le i,j\le n$ (your condition 2, but with the range corrected so as to only include $n$ elements). Namely, from this it follows that the function

$$g(\overline x)=\overline{ax}$$

is a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: I don't understand the overline notation. Please explain...

Comment: @ShreyAryan I use the notation $\overline x$ to denote the residue class of $x$, so as to not confuse it with the number $x$, that's all.

Comment: That will likely be confusing to any reader who is not familiar with quotient rings, e.g. most students of elementary number theory.